# Scala equivalent of combining generic types in Java?

Tags: scala, generics

In Java I have an interface with generic types defined like this:

```
public interface A extends B<C & D> {
  ...
}
```

How would the combined generic type of `C & D` be expressed in Scala? I've tried:

```
A <: B[C & D]
```

but it obviously gives me a compile error.

Comment: Perhaps you should add it as an answer so that I can accept?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax is `C with D`. Check http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/compound-types.html for more info.